# Nested if statement within for loop [JAVA/LibGDX]

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, nested

So I got my code to work this more of a question in regards to Java and why it worked the way I got it VS. why it didn't work the first way I wrote it. This is the original code I wrote.

```
private void renderGUIExtraLives (SpriteBatch batch){
    float x = GUIcamera.viewportWidth - 50 - Constants.LIVES_START * 50;
    float y = -15;
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
        if (worldController.lives <= i) {
            batch.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            batch.draw(Assets.instance.bunny.head, x + i * 50, y, 50, 50, 120, 100, 0.35f, -0.35f, 0);
            batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This didn't work, it threw no errors, but it did not draw the lives to the screen, all I did was remove the curly braces of the if statement like so:

```
private void renderGUIExtraLives (SpriteBatch batch){
    float x = GUIcamera.viewportWidth - 50 - Constants.LIVES_START * 50;
    float y = -15;
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
        if (worldController.lives <= i) 
            batch.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            batch.draw(Assets.instance.bunny.head, x + i * 50, y, 50, 50, 120, 100, 0.35f, -0.35f, 0);
            batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

And now magically it worked, can some explain why it worked after I removed the curly braces from the nested if statement? I would really appreciate it, as well as any discussion regarding this topic would be great to read if someone has a link to a similar question or answer here on Stack.

Comment: If you do not write the curly brackets after an `if (...)` (or an `for(...)` or a `while(...)`), only the **next statement** (in your case `batch.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);`) forms the body of the preceding construct. In Java, indentation has no semantical effect (there are languages - like Python - where the indentation is part of the semantcs) and why you should always write the curly brackets (even if the body of the construct consists of only one statement). Look at [luk2302's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44102153/4216641) for some clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong and misleading. If you remove the braces after the `if` only the next statement is conditionally executed. That means the code basically is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
    if (worldController.lives <= i) 
        batch.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    batch.draw(Assets.instance.bunny.head, x + i * 50, y, 50, 50, 120, 100, 0.35f, -0.35f, 0);
    batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Should be clear why it "magically works" now, it just draws unconditionally.